# Error Installing ADFS 3.0

Tags: adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

i'm trying to install ADFS on a new installation of a Win Server 2012R2 and I get an error in the post-deployment configuration. The Domain Controller is a Win Server 2008R2. Please someone help me, i've been trying to solve this for 3 days.

The error says:

> Schema verification failed for database 'AdfsConfiguration'.
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
>   Failed to restart the current database. The current database is switched to master.

This is the error log after the installation:

2015-04-29 12:46:55.93 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Windows Internal Database (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

2015-04-29 12:46:55.97 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.97 Server      All rights reserved.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.97 Server      Server process ID is 1532.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.97 Server      System Manufacturer: 'VMware, Inc.', System Model: 'VMware Virtual Platform'.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.98 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.98 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'C:\Windows\WID\Log\error.log'.

2015-04-29 12:46:55.98 Server      The service account is 'NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID'. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:56.00 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -w 65535
     -T 1617
     -K
     -e C:\Windows\WID\Log\error.log
     -l C:\Windows\WID\Data\mastlog.ldf
     -d C:\Windows\WID\Data\master.mdf

2015-04-29 12:46:56.00 Server      Command Line Startup Parameters:
     -S "MSWIN8.SQLWID"
     -s "MICROSOFT##WID"

2015-04-29 12:46:56.54 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 1 total logical processors; using 1 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:56.54 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:56.54 Server      Detected 4095 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:56.54 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.

2015-04-29 12:46:59.38 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000001:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000001:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:59.41 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:46:59.42 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.

2015-04-29 12:46:59.57 spid7s      Starting up database 'master'.

2015-04-29 12:47:00.20 spid7s      The password regeneration attempt for SA was successful.

2015-04-29 12:47:00.25 spid7s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.

2015-04-29 12:47:00.25 spid7s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:00.26 spid7s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:00.48 spid7s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".

2015-04-29 12:47:00.50 spid7s      Server name is 'GARWEB01\MICROSOFT##WID'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.00 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.16 spid9s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.21 spid7s      Starting up database 'msdb'.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.24 spid13s     The service master key regeneration was successful.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.24 spid13s     Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\MICROSOFT##WID\tsql\query ].

2015-04-29 12:47:01.25 spid9s      The resource database build version is 11.00.2100. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.26 spid13s     Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is disabled on this edition of SQL Server. If you want to use a dedicated administrator connection, restart SQL Server using the trace flag 7806. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.43 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.

2015-04-29 12:47:01.87 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.

2015-04-29 12:47:03.65 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.

2015-04-29 12:47:07.48 spid16s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

2015-04-29 12:47:07.52 spid16s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

2015-04-29 12:47:07.72 spid16s     Service Broker manager has started.

2015-04-29 12:47:08.13 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized using CLR version v4.0.30319 from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319.

2015-04-29 12:47:09.13 spid7s      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:09.28 spid7s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:47:09.59 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 0 seconds. Working set (KB): 5648, committed (KB): 119708, memory utilization: 4%.

2015-04-29 12:49:03.32 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 331 seconds. Working set (KB): 24060, committed (KB): 98188, memory utilization: 24%.

2015-04-29 12:52:52.70 spid51      Attempting to load library 'xpsqlbot.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:52:52.74 spid51      Using 'xpsqlbot.dll' version '2011.110.2100' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_qv'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 12:53:05.74 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 601 seconds. Working set (KB): 38888, committed (KB): 98548, memory utilization: 39%.

2015-04-29 12:58:19.65 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 928 seconds. Working set (KB): 39020, committed (KB): 98548, memory utilization: 39%.

2015-04-29 13:03:46.67 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 1258 seconds. Working set (KB): 39580, committed (KB): 98892, memory utilization: 40%.

2015-04-29 13:09:17.59 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 1523 seconds. Working set (KB): 39568, committed (KB): 98940, memory utilization: 39%.

2015-04-29 13:15:34.11 spid3s      A significant part of sql server process memory has been paged out. This may result in a performance degradation. Duration: 1853 seconds. Working set (KB): 39776, committed (KB): 99044, memory utilization: 40%.

2015-04-29 13:16:33.02 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.

2015-04-29 13:16:33.02 Logon       Login failed for user 'GARANTIZAR\BackupUSR'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'AdfsConfiguration'. [CLIENT: ]

2015-04-29 13:16:48.56 Logon       Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.

2015-04-29 13:16:48.56 Logon       Login failed for user 'GARANTIZAR\BackupUSR'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'AdfsConfiguration'. [CLIENT: ]

2015-04-29 13:16:50.57 spid51      Starting up database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:16:51.38 spid51      Setting database option SINGLE_USER to ON for database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:16:51.88 spid34s     Could not start Service Broker for database id: 5. A problem is preventing SQL Server from starting Service Broker. Check the SQL Server error log for additional messages.

2015-04-29 13:16:51.97 spid34s     Error: 9645, Severity: 16, State: 3.

2015-04-29 13:16:51.97 spid34s     An error occurred in the service broker manager, Error: 3602, State: 124.

2015-04-29 13:16:59.89 spid51      Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:17:00.23 spid51      Starting up database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:17:00.34 spid51      Failed to verify Authenticode signature on DLL 'C:\Windows\WID\Binn\DBVerify\adfsconfigDbVerify.dll'.

2015-04-29 13:17:58.86 spid51      Starting up database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:18:20.94 spid54      Attempting to load library 'xpstar.dll' into memory. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

2015-04-29 13:18:21.11 spid54      Using 'xpstar.dll' version '2011.110.2100' to execute extended stored procedure 'xp_instance_regread'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

2015-04-29 13:18:23.04 spid54      Starting up database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:18:42.36 spid54      Setting database option MULTI_USER to ON for database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:18:42.41 spid54      Starting up database 'AdfsConfiguration'.

2015-04-29 13:18:42.44 spid54      Failed to verify Authenticode signature on DLL 'C:\Windows\WID\Binn\DBVerify\adfsconfigDbVerify.dll'.

Answer (score 1):

I found myself the error, the problem was that the Windows Internal Database service was running with the account **NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID** which was configured by windows. I configured the service to start with **Local System account** and everything worked ok.